# OdooV13 replace product image from binary field on hover(onmouseover)

Tags: image, odoo

Let's say that I have a field "mynewimage", where the image is being uploaded and field type is binary. I need to replace the product image with it. I can't do that directly in XML, because I need to do that on hover(Or maybe I could who knows ;)) How I could replace the image on hover? Is there a way to get a image path from a binary field?

Comment: with your field 'mynewimage' on mouse hover which image should be there or replace it?

Comment: @DipenShah mynewimage is where image is stored. I defined it with fields.Binary() and widget:image. So, I upload image directly inside a mynewimage field. And it is the image, which I need on mouse hover.